# Python Mechanize response on submit

Tags: python, mechanize-python

I'm trying to fill a form and print its response page in Mechanize, but  when I use `browser.reponse()`, I get the response

`<response_seek_wrapper at 0x21f0648 whose wrapped object = <closeable_response at 0x21fc3a0 whose fp = <socket._fileobject object at 0x021EDD70>>>`

How do I print the html that I get as a response?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think browser.response().read() will return that you expected.

Source : http://www.pythonforbeginners.com/cheatsheet/python-mechanize-cheat-sheet